# How to create a math equation is a sql call PHP

Tags: php

I don't know if this is possible. I have a table in which I would like to find the total amount of times `Yes` appears in `recalled` column, and then I want to find total row count for this dancer. After that I want to divide the the amount of times `Yes` appears by the total row count for each `dancer_id`.

The `dancer_id` is in an array so there can be many dancers that I need this information for.

This is how I attempted it:

```
 //GET OVERALL TOTAL   
                $overall_total = " SELECT * from mark_cards1 where dancer_id1='$champId'";
                $overall_Res = mysqli_query($con,$overall_total);
                $total_MC = mysqli_num_rows($overall_Res);

                //GET RECALL FOR OVERALL PLACEMENT CHART
                $recallsql = "SELECT * from mark_cards1 where dancer_id1='$champId' and was_recalled = 'Yes'";
                $recallRes = mysqli_query($con,$recallsql);
                $total_recall = mysqli_num_rows($recallRes);

                //RECALL COUNT / FEIS COUNT

                $feis_total = $total_MC; 

                $recall_total = $total_recall; 

                $overall_placement = $recall_total / $feis_total;


                echo "
                ['$champName', '$champlvl', '$champGender', '$champTeacher', $champAge, $overall_placement, 5],
                ";
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? Can I get this information in one sql call?

Comment: You can use the `case` method in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below query at your end and let me if you have any query regarding this.

```
select 
count(
    case when dancer_id1 = '$champId' then 1 else null end
) as total_MC, 
count(
    case when (
        dancer_id1 = '$champId' 
        and was_recalled  = 'Yes'
    ) then 1 else null end
) as total_recall 
from 
 mark_cards
```

After running this query you will get two counts related variable and divide them so you can get your desired result.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!